# Design patterns for PHP - visitor pattern vs servant pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I find these two patterns are similar (and the most of other behavioral patterns)

visitor pattern,

```
interface Visitor 
{
    public function visit(Visitable $Visitable);
} 
interface Visitable 
{
    public function accept(Visitor $Vsitor);
}
class ConcreteVisitable implements Visitable
{
    public $items = array();

    public function addItem($item)
    {
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }

    public function accept(Visitor $Vsitor)
    {
        $Vsitor->visit($this);
    }
}
class ConcreteVisitor implements Visitor 
{
    protected $info;

    public function visit(Visitable $Visitable)
    {
        echo "Object: ", get_class($Visitable), " <br/>";
        $items = get_object_vars($Visitable)['items'];

        foreach ($items as $index => $value) {
            echo $index . ": ", $value, " <br/>";
        }
    }
}
// Usage example
$ConcreteVisitable = new ConcreteVisitable();
$ConcreteVisitor = new ConcreteVisitor();
$ConcreteVisitable->addItem('item 1');
$ConcreteVisitable->addItem('item 2');
$ConcreteVisitable->addItem('item 3');
$ConcreteVisitable->accept($ConcreteVisitor);
```

servant pattern,

```
// Servant.
interface Servant
{
    //  
}

// Servable. AKA Boss/ Master/ Authority
interface Servable
{
    //
}

// Concrete Servable.
class ConcreteServable implements Servable
{
    private $position;

    public function setPosition($position)
    {
        $this->position = $position . '<br/>';
    }

    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }
}

// Concrete Servant.
class ConcreteServant implements Servant
{
    // Method, which will move Servable implementing class to position where.
    public function moveTo(Servable $Servable, $arg) 
    {
        // Do some other stuff to ensure it moves smoothly and nicely, this is
        // the place to offer the functionality.
        $Servable->setPosition($arg);
    }
}

$ConcreteServable = new ConcreteServable();
$ConcreteServant = new ConcreteServant();

$ConcreteServant->moveTo($ConcreteServable, 10);
echo $ConcreteServable->getPosition();

$ConcreteServant->moveTo($ConcreteServable, 20);
echo $ConcreteServable->getPosition();
```

Can you tell the differences between them? (unless the servant pattern example is incorrect??)

Answer (score 2):

in fact, servant is simpler than visitor pattern. The class diagram is similar, too. 
In visitor pattern, Visitor object rely on visited elements, but serviced object not.

Comment: `visited elements` - do you mean the `ConcreteVisitable` in my example above?

Comment: Yep, that is because Visitor Object  has to do something with Visitable Object !

Comment: And the Servant Object don't? isn't this `public function moveTo(Servable $Servable, $arg)` same as `public function visit(Visitable $Visitable)`?

Comment: Our description differs.  I mean the serviced object (not servant object). In your program, serviced object is correspondingly Servable object.

Comment: Aw thanks. `In your program, serviced object is correspondingly Servable object.` so should a `serviced object` correspond with `Servable object` or not?

Comment: Servable in your program is Serviced in my code. Servable should have or not keep a reference of Servant Object. Meanwhile, in Visitor Pattern, an Visitor must have a reference of one or more Elements iteratively.

Comment: here is my code on github about servant pattern, written in java. Hope it help. https://github.com/tyybjcc/Design-Patterns-in-java/tree/master/DesignPatterns/src/com/designpattern/extra/servant

Comment: @tian you mean `Visitable` know about the existence of `Visitor` via this method: `public function accept(Visitor $Vsitor)` but `Servable` does not know that `Servant` exists at all?